# How To Combine Two-Step URL into One Link?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to link to a specific web page that requires two URL's as follows.

To get to my desired page, first I have to enter:

http://www.shipmentlink.com/servlet/TDB1_CargoTracking.do

Then I have to enter:

javascript:frmCntrMoveDetail%28%27XINU8187202%27%29;

I want to place this in a single href.  What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can prefill a field and select a radio button with just the URL but I think I see what you're trying to do. On the upside, you can use PHP and Curl to [create a POST request](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/examples/).

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.shipmentlink.com/servlet/TDB1_CargoTracking.do");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "BL=&CNTR=XINU8187202&bkno=&TYPE=CNTR&NO=&NO=&NO=&NO=&NO=&SEL=s_cntr&NO=XINU8187202");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

echo $server_output;

?>
```

The output would look like...

[image]

Comment: Thx for your answer!  Good answer, but won't work for me as I'm not a PHP user.  I will have to figure out how to do something similar in Javascript.  I need to link shipping containers to their tracking screen to incorporate in my website.  All of them have RESTful URL's except this one actually requires two entries/pages/postbacks to get to the page I need, with a wait until the page is loaded before I can use the next post.  I need to include that in one href - was hoping to do that without JS or JQuery code, but doesn't seem possible.